# Can mathematics help a poor researcher? ODE, convergence, solution without an exact solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, stability-in-odes

**Background information**

I am trying to model the thermal efficiency of a Cogeneration engine based on two Ordinary Differential Equations (ODE)s, based  Newton’s law of cooling. 
These [equations](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/19401490802588424) were originally developed by a group of scientists working for the international project (if interested, see [COGEN-SIM](http://www.ecbcs.org/annexes/annex42.htm)!)
 The equations are as follows:
$$
[MC]_{eng}\frac{dT_{eng}}{dt} = K_{eng} ({T_{eng}-T_{cw,o}})+K_{loss} ({T_{eng}-T_{amb}})
$$
$$
[MC]_{cw}\frac{dT_{cw,o}}{dt} = [mc_{p}]_{cw} ({T_{cw,i}-T_{cw,o}})+K_{eng} ({T_{eng}-T_{cw,o}})
$$

**Description of the equations**

First equation: the thermal energy transferred from the engine ($eng$) to the the ambient ($amb$)

Second equation: the thermal energy transferred from  the engine ($eng$) to cooling water ($cw$)

**Problem statement**

In their case, the models were developed and calibrated based on the experiments which followed the modelling part of the project. The error and $R^2$  were calculated and finally the model was validated.

Unlike them (them rich boys of science), I am not a part of international consortium and the research group that I am working does not have fund or connections to buy a Cogeneration engine to conduct experiments.

**Problem**: I do not know the exact solution - I don't have any measurements of $T_{eng}$ or $T_{cw,o}$.

**Aim**: To solve the mentioned equations without knowing the exact solution.

**Questions**

1. Considering the case above, does the stated aim make sense? In other words, is it reasonable (scientifically/mathematically sound) to solve ODE without knowing the exact solution? If yes, how am I going to understand that the solution has converged? What kind of assumptions should I make?
2. I am planning to use **RK4** from the Runga-Kutte methods family to solve the aforementioned equations. RK4 requires the boundary and step-size as inputs to estimate the solution. 
   Now I am not quite sure how the boundary and the step-size contributes to the solution: The result of my model is consisted of the electricity and thermal output of the cogeneration unit for every minute of the day (1440 minutes/day). Therefore, for every minute I need to calculate $T_{eng}$ and $T_{cw,o}$. Let's assume that I have step-size of 1 ($h=1$) and my boundary limit is 20 ($x_{final}=20$).

   2.1. Is the following statement correct?: "*The solver will estimate the $T_{eng}$ and $T_{cw,o}$ after 20 iterations for every minute of the day*".

   2.2. What are the parameters to be considered when the boundary limit and the step size are being chosen?

Comment: What do you mean by 'solve'? You seem to imply that you are not necessarily looking for an exact (closed form) solution. So what kind of solution are you looking for?

Comment: If you know all the parameters of the equations and initial/boundary conditions, then it is possible to solve the equations. Measurements are only needed to verify that solution of ODE agrees with the real measurements of the phenomena that ODE models

Comment: Your writing is pretty brilliant.

Comment: @user2520938  by solving I mean reaching an exact solution if possible, if not an estimation. Sorry if this does not make sense. Can you elaborate on what options I might have, so I can do some background reading.

Comment: @Tomas I know the initial condition. I can also assign a boundary condition. Does the boundary condtion work like, a constraint in optimisation problems (e.g. x1 is non-zero, etc.). Considering the example which I explained, what would be my solution? The values of $T_{eng}$ and $T_{cw,o}$ at the last iteration?

Comment: Not quite. Take for example an ODE $y'=1$. It has an infinite number of solutions with general form $y(t)=t+C$, i.e.different solutions will differ only by a constant $C$. To obtain a unique solution (i.e. one solution completely describing the situation you are handling) you need an additional information. For example, assume you know that at time $t=0$ the value of unknown variable is $y(0)=1$. Then using this additional condition (or a constraint if you prefer so) we have a unique solution $y(t)=t+1$

Comment: In case of your equations, the solution that you will obtain is a time series $(t,T_{eng}(t))$. Aproximative methods (like Runge-Kutta) will produce at each full iteration a time point and a value of the quantity at that time point

Comment: @Tomas I am still confused: for example, for 24-hours I'll loop through $60(min)x24(h)$ entries of input data, using them as input for these equations to get the $T_{eng}$ and $T_{cw,o}$. Then I will calculate the thermal efficiency accordingly. Now, this is a time-series and $(t,T_{eng}(t))$, will be calculated for each minute(a 1440 row vector for each of $T_{eng}$ and $T_{cw,o})$. My question is what is $t$ representing here?  If we assume that I have 20 iteration per every whole iteration, is my solution at every calculation step (at every minute of the day) $(20,T_{eng}(20))$?

Comment: @FarhadAzer $t$ is time, as it is an independent variable of your system of ODE. It seems to me, that you do not understand how differential equations are solved (particularly the Cauchy problem) and you have a very vague idea about the aproximation methods used to numerically solve differential equations. I would strongly suggest to learn the basics before trying to solve your system.

Comment: The linked paper, whatever its worth, costs $ 35.00 to read.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  Sorry, here is a link to a public access one (after page 85): http://www.ecbcs.org/docs/Annex_42_Cogen_Model_Specifications.pdf